# Update notification

Tags: release-loki, updates, appcenter

AppCenter's automatic update notification doesn't work anymore for a few days caused by missing file /usr/share/applications/io.elementary.appcenter-daemon.desktop.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct and I can confirm this issue. However, StackExchange is for asking questions. It would be very helpful for the elementary developers if you raised this as an issue on the [AppCenter GitHub repository](https://github.com/elementary/appcenter/issues)

If your question was how to fix this manually, you can create the `/usr/share/applications/io.elementary.appcenter-daemon.desktop` with the `Exec` key set to `appcenter -s`